# SSIS: connectionstring breaks after deploy from VS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, deployment, ssis

I have a server with 64-bit MS SQL Server 2016 installed.

I have a SSIS package which contains ACE OLEDB 12 connection manager, which builds a connection string using package variable FileName (String).

So, if I deploy this package to SSISDB from Visual Studio 2015 (DataTools) just from the server itself, all is ok.

But, when I deploy the same package using Visual Studio 2015 (DataTools) from my local PC, it corrupts the connection string: all non-ASCII symbols became broken! So, the package fails validation and not starts on the server after deploy.
So the problem comes when I use my local VS to deploy the package / project;
if I go to SSMS on my local PC, connect to server, go to the SSISDB, and deploy a project from here, the connection string deploys properly.

What setting (maybe, collation, or connection string codepage) can be changed to let me deploy a package / project from VS? 
I've searched in project and solution properties with no success. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: use ACE OLEDB 15 provider instead of 12.

Comment: Note: Use Deploy option to deploy entire project. If you deploy just one package, connection string will be broken!